# How to fetch csv data using URL?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am able to fetch the data but it is incomplete.

CSV URL : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv

The library that I am using to fetch the data is `csv_reader`, https://pub.dev/packages/csv_reader

code snippet :

```
Future<List<DataRow>> fetchRows() async {

    var myCSV = CSV.from(
    url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv',
      delimiter: ",",
      title: false);

    await myCSV.initFinished; 

    print(myCSV.shape); //prints 28x71

    return [];
}
```

The URL has 274 rows but the above snippet is printing 28.

How can I fetch all 274 rows?

Comment: @Mech yes at each row all the sections are separated by `,`

Answer (score 0):

Flutter has a character limit on the print function. You can print the entire output using the following function:

```
void fullPrint(String text) {
  final pattern = RegExp('.{1,800}');
  pattern.allMatches(text).forEach((match) => print(match.group(0)));
}
```

Then to print the whole output, call the newly created function:
`fullPrint(myCSV.shape);`